# Python: How to chain tuple in a list by the next item value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get expected result from the list of tuple in **Python 3**?

```
[('I', 'N'),('love', 'V'),('Miley', 'N'),('Cyrus', 'N'),('but', 'ADV'),('hate', 'V'),('Liam', 'N'),('Hemsworth', 'N')]
```

Expected results:

```
['I', 'love', 'Miley Cyrus', 'but', 'hate', 'Liam Hemsworth']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to *group by* the second element, then extract the first element of each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [('I', 'N'), ('love', 'V'), ('Miley', 'N'), ('Cyrus', 'N'), ('but', 'ADV'), ('hate', 'V'), ('Liam', 'N'),
        ('Hemsworth', 'N')]

result = [' '.join(t[0] for t in group) for k, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(1))]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['I', 'love', 'Miley Cyrus', 'but', 'hate', 'Liam Hemsworth']
```

The above [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is equivalent to the following for loop:

```
result = []
for k, group in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(1)):
    result.append(' '.join(t[0] for t in group))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby
data = [('I', 'N'),('love', 'V'),('Miley', 'N'),('Cyrus', 'N'),('but', 'ADV'),('hate', 'V'),('Liam', 'N'),('Hemsworth', 'N')]

result = [" ".join(m for m, _ in v) for k, v in groupby(data, lambda x: x[1])]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['I', 'love', 'Miley Cyrus', 'but', 'hate', 'Liam Hemsworth']
```